# Can't submit the same form twice within one page load (via jQuery and AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input, submit

I'm toying with writing a mock terminal webpage for my server management application. Basically, using jquery, ajax and php's shell_exec(), I'm emulating a terminal.

The input line of the terminal is basically just an `input` element wrapped in a form. There's a jquery handler that fires off the ajax request when the form is submitted (enter key is pressed).

Everything works when I submit it the first time (when I send the first command). However, once I try to send the second one, the page scrolls all the way to the top and the form isn't submitted.

Here's the jquery:

```
$("#terminal-form").unbind('submit').submit(function() {
            var current_dir = $("#path").text();
            var command = $("#terminal-input").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "terminal.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { current_dir: current_dir, command: command },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#terminal table").remove();
                    $("#terminal").append("root@gallactica:" + current_dir + " $ " + command + "<br>");
                    if (data['output'] != '') {
                        $("#terminal").append(data['output'] + "<br>");
                    }
                    $("#terminal").append("<table class='terminal-content'><tr><td nowrap='nowrap' style='overflow:auto;whitespace:nowrap'>root@gallactica:" + data['wd'] + "$<td style='width:99%'><form style='margin:0px;padding:0px' id='terminal-form'><input id='terminal-input' type='text'></input></form></td></tr></table>");
                    $("#terminal-input").focus();
                }
            })
            return false;
        })
```

The `success` handler basically just removes the old form and inserts the results in plaintext, essentially giving the illusion that it's all interactive.

Here's the PHP backend:

```
<?php

$current_dir = $_POST['current_dir']; // get current directory
$command = $_POST['command']; // get the command to run
chdir($current_dir); // change into the right directory

if (substr($command, 0, 2) == "cd") {
    chdir(substr($command, 3));
    $output = "";
} else {
    $output = shell_exec($command); // get the command's output
}

$wd = shell_exec('pwd'); // get the current working directory
$result = array('wd' => $wd, 'output' => $output); // create array
$result = json_encode($result); // convert to json for jquery
echo $result;
```

The problem is when I go to submit a second command. I don't even think the form is being submitted correctly. I did some googleing and found that you need to unbind the handler, which I'm doing, but it still isn't working.

Comment: You could probably accomplish the same thing while replacing less of the DOM. It's relatively quite expensive to to remove the entire `<form>`, add a new form, and re-bind the event handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you replace an element you lose it's event handlers, even if you replace with exact same html. What you are seeing is form being submitted by default browser method which is causing a page reload

To get around this you can delegate the submit handler so it will work for future form loaded also

```
$(document).on('submit', "#terminal-form",function() {
   /* handler code*/
})
```

This will bind the handler to the `document` which always exists, and will target only the ID for your specific form. Will not interfere with any other forms submit handlers in page

Comment: Cool, this worked perfectly and thanks for the explanation. I'm not getting into the handler but the ajax seems to be messing up.

Comment: use browser console to inspect the AJAX request to help troubleshoot. Can see status, data sent & received etc

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. Cheers.